# Trying to dynamically change css with React componentDidUpdate causes max stack size exceeded error on a className change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, meteor

I am trying to change the css on a div, the background colour, basically if the user has 'favourited' this particular item I want the background to change and if he then clicks it again it should change back to the default colour as he no longer has 'favourited' this item.

I have the functionality working for the number change but the css is messing me up. I have tried a few things...

first off here is my code for the component...

```
constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = {favVoteIsSelected:''};
}

<div onClick={this.vote.bind(this)} className={'votes__element '+ 
    this.state.favVoteIsSelected} id='fav'>
    <p>{this.props.item.rating.fav.count}</p>
</div>
```

The on onClick function(this.vote.bind(this)) just calls a Meteor Method that will take care of the database section which I then use as a basis to render the css.

What I have then done is made this function to change the className that will then change the background colour.

```
userHasVoted(){
    let voteCheckFav = this.props.item.rating.fav.data;
    voteCheckFav.map((user) => {
        if (user.createdBy.userId === Meteor.userId()){
            this.setState({favVoteIsSelected:'votes__element--selected'});
        } else {
            this.setState({favVoteIsSelected:''});
        }
    });
} // end of user has voted
```

This function will then change the state to the className that will change the background colour. The data field is just an array of the users data, username and id.

Thats the basic set up, the issues come in where I then try to implement those change refreshers. The first option i tried was to use componentDidUpdate() and then run the userHasVoted function inside that just went on an infinite loop and then displayed the error...

> Exception from Tracker recompute function:
>
> > RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

It did works for the initial background colour change but doesn't change it back to default, after i exceeded the stack size.

the next option I tried after some googling and more research was to put the Tracker.autorun function into a componentDidMount(), and call the userHasVoted function from there, this stops the looping issue resulting in the above error but doesn't seem to update the css of the page.

I am just a little stuck here, I will keep trying and doing more research but cant seem to get it right. I am VERY new to meteor and reach so I am sorry if this is a super stupid problem. There is no need to fully answer my question if you know there is a thread that has answered it already, but please can you point me in the right direction?

Thanks in advance,

Chris

Comment: dunno about meteor but `componentDidUpdate` is considered too late to mutate state again - you can work with the DOM tree but updating state will cause an infinite loop indeed. `componentWillReceiveProps(newProps)` is where you want to prepare your state to avoid this.

Answer (score 0):

This feels like an abuse of state - your css class only depends on props and the user's data, there doesn't seem to be state carried in the UI. I'm also not clear on why you're doing a `.map()` when the state is a scalar. If `this.props.item.rating.fav.data` is an array then you're repeatedly changing the same scalar state during the map loop which is part of your problem.

A more typical pattern would be to just create a function that returns the class you need.

```
constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = {favVoteIsSelected:''};
}

userHasVoted(userId){
  return `votes_element ${userId === Meteor.userId() ? 'selected' : ''}`;
}
```

...

```
<div
  onClick={this.vote.bind(this)}
  className={this.userHasVoted(this.props.item.createdBy.userId)}
>
  <p>{this.props.item.rating.fav.count}</p>
</div>
```

Assuming that `this.props.item.createdBy.userId` is the `userId` of the current item (I assume your ` is being rendered in a loop).

Note also that your css is a bit odd. Your code looks like it would produce `votes__element votes__element--selected' or`votes__element`as the two possibilities. You probably just want`votes__element`and`votes__element selected`with`selected` being a class that changes the appearance of *selected* elements.